# Use Atmel Studio as General C Compiler

Tags: c++, c, atmelstudio

I'm trying to dig in and learn C. My end goal is to head more toward AVR programming and hardware so I downloaded AtmelStudio.

I'm working through a C primer book and wondering how to write console programs in AtmelStudio?  All the project types seem to be AVR/ARM focused (makes sense) and require me to pick a Device.

Can I use AtmelStudio for just compiling simple programs and running them in a cmd window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For programs intended to run in a Windows console window, may I suggest using MinGW?  That's a port of the GCC C/C++/etc. compilers used by Atmel Studio, and the Code::Blocks IDE makes a nice match for that under Windows.  I usually don't recommend software bundles, but there's a handy binary download codeblocks.org with a stable Code::Blocks and a recent stable MinGW.

[Code::Block Binary Downloads](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)

As for using AtmelStudio to compile programs to run in a "cmd" window, the compilers used will will be some sort of cross-compiler for a CPU and OS that is not what you are running on.  Unless you have an emulator for that target platform that runs in Windows console, then I think you're out of luck.  Embedded systems typically don't have keyboard or console devices, so real programs won't have a classical Unix-style `main()` function.  You still can write and test functions that don't do console I/O or system calls.  Properly coded, those will recompile without changes to run in either environment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm happy to use whatever will be best. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it in AtmelStudio so I could get to know my way around the IDE for the future when I do more with AVR chips.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible. You can only use the simulator to investigate the simulated internal state of a microcontroller and that's it.

There is stuff out there like [avrtest](http://winavr.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/winavr/avrtest/) or  [simavr](https://github.com/buserror/simavr) but I'm not sure if this is working for you.

If you just want to learn C before getting into microcontroller development - which is a rather good idea - just get another IDE like [Eclipse C/C++](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunasr1a) and start with that. After you have the basics you will be able to debug a microcontroller using just the AVR simulator as well.

[Here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/printf-question) is another (possible) solution to what you want but I guess that is not an answer you want to get as a beginner.